# What are these and how do I remove them using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string from user input that is in the following format:

```
"foo\U+FFE2\U+FFB5\U+FFE2\U+FFB5"
```

When I view this it does not show anything in the browser or terminal, but they are definitely there.

What are they and how do I remove all junk chars like these to end up with just 'foo'?

I know I could just remove these specific ones but there maybe other different ones that I want just the text value from.

Any ideas?

Comment: ([U+FFE2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffe2/index.htm), [U+FFB5](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffb5/index.htm))

Comment: Are you not handling/expecting unicode?  The `U+FFB5` is a Korean alphabet character, it may seem like junk to you, but an entire country would take issue with that.

Comment: The internet is no longer based on merely ASCII, Win-1252, ISO-8859-1 or Latin character sets. Unless you have specific requirements that limit your inputs, you need to be prepared to handle UTF-8 and any other Unicode set thrown at you. Otherwise, you need to specify that *ONLY* certain character sets or languages are supported. It's a human-interface nicety.

Answer (score 1):

I see the two main variants:

1. with `#split`/`#join` pair:

   ```
   "fooффф".split('').select{|x|x.ord <= 127}.join
   # => "foo"
   ```
2. with `#unpack`/`#pack` pair:

   ```
   "fooффф".unpack('U*').select{|x| x <= 127}.pack('U*')
   # => "foo"
   ```